# How to access a method of a child class in c#?

Tags: c#

I need to access `essential` parameter of `gameObject.AddComponent()` when it returns an instance of some class `...`

The `gameObject.AddComponent()` function has return type `Component`.

The inheritance in the project looks this way:

```
Object <- Component <- Behaviour <- MonoBehaviour <- TDefault <- ...
```

Where `A`<-`B` means "`B` is inherited from `A`".

I have no access to `MonoBehaviour` or its parents. They are provided by the Engine.

`TDefault` is the class from which I inherit all my classes but `TEssential`. It is written by me. It has `essential` property of type `TEssential`

Casting `print(gameObject.AddComponent(effect_name) as TDefault);` prints `null`.

```
print((gameObject.AddComponent(effect_name) as dynamic));
```

produces

> Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information.
>   output was:error CS0518: The predefined type
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite is not defined or imported
>   error CS0518: The predefined type
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite 1' is not defined or imported

I tried adding

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite;
```

but it only changes the error

> Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:error CS0518: The predefined type `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite' is not defined or imported
>   error CS0518: The predefined type`System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1' is not defined or imported

I am sure that the returned variable has the type `...`. The built-in editor shows it correctly.

How can I get the property?

Comment: What is `print()`?  How do you know the return from `AddComponent()` is `TDefault`?  What do you get from `gameObject.AddComponent(effect_name).GetType().ToString()`?

Comment: I get `int_param` which is the type I manually inherit from `TDefault`. print(); is built-in by the engine function for debugging. If I'm not mistaken, it simply calls Debug.Log()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is Casting to Interface:

1)

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using NExtensionMethods;

    public class TDefault:MonoBehaviour,IDefault
    {
        public  TEssentail essential=new TEssentail();
        public TEssentail get_essential()
        {
            if(essential==null)
                essential=new TEssentail();
            return essential;
        }

        public TDefault ()
        {
        }
    }
```

2)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public interface IDefault
{

    TEssentail get_essential();
}
```

3)`TEssentail ess=(gameObject.AddComponent(effect_name) as IDefault).get_essential();`

Answer (score 0):

Add component has a generic overload so you shoudl be able to do:

```
effect_name newComponent = gameObject.AddComponent<effect_name>();
```

after a little more research. are you sure that `effect_name` is inheriting `TDefault`?

Comment: Generic version of AddComponent doesn't accept type parameters. I can only call AddComponent<TDefault>() which creates new TDefault

Comment: I never said that `effect_name` is inheriting `TDefault`. It is a string, that specifies the name of the class, instance of which I'm trying to add.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access to a method of a class (or component) attached to a gameobject (being a child or not), you can use `gameObject.GetComponent<Myclass(or component)>().MyMethod([params])`.

If you want to access to a child of a game `object ->  gameobject.Transform.getChild(#)`.

If you want to add a component then use the `AddComponent` method.

Comment: I want to add a component. Besides, I want a reference to a property of this component. I cannot use GetComponent() before I add it. After I add it, how can I distinguish it from other components of the same type?

Comment: I have never had more components of the same type in the same gameObject, I use a third GameObject to manage troublesome items, or I change/use/modify the current component on the gameobject, still, not sure what kind of component would require having 2 of the same type. good luck